# how to program the terminal emulator so it can trigger actions based on action keys

Tags: terminal

I want to see what happens when for example I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> on terminal. I want to view some logs for it and want to reprogram the behavior for it so when pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> it not only opens a new terminal tab but continues from where I was in my current tab. So, If I was `ssh` into some machine then if i press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> then in the new tab I want to be connected to that machine and be in the same folder too. The terminal I am using is MATE Terminal 1.8.1

Comment: That sounds like a function of the terminal product you're using so at the very least, you'll need to tell us which terminal software it is.

Comment: You should consider rephrasing your title, as it doesn't really match what you're asking for. You seem to be asking about `how to program the terminal emulator so it can trigger actions based on action keys` or something like that.